# Encryption from the load balancer to the backends not working using HTTPS backend

Tags: apache, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have created a load balancer in GCP for using HTTPS to forward it to the HTTPS backend group.
I have configured the Instance to use HTTPS by creating a certificate on the instance and when I curl from the instance itself I get the following

```
curl https://localhost
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.


root@instance:/var/log/apache2# curl https://localhost -k
<WebPage content>
```

I checked the GCP documentation on [**Encryption from the load balancer to the backends**](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/encryption-to-the-backends#secure_backend_protocol_considerations) and have configured the backend and health check as stated.

However, the health check shows UNHEALTHY, and the health check log shows

```
healthCheckProbeResult: {
   connectLatency: "0.000651s"    
   detailedHealthState: "TIMEOUT"    
   healthCheckProtocol: "HTTPS"    
   healthState: "UNHEALTHY"    
   ipAddress: "10.8.1.4"    
   previousDetailedHealthState: "UNKNOWN"    
   previousHealthState: "UNHEALTHY"    
   probeCompletionTimestamp: "2021-08-11T07:46:06.973978919Z"    
   probeRequest: "/user"    
   probeResultText: "HTTP response: , Error: Protocol error"    
   probeSourceIp: "35.191.1.154"    
   responseLatency: "0.002054s"    
   targetIp: "<internal IP>"    
   targetPort: 443    
  }
```

When I only use HTTP, by changing apache and backend configurations, the site works fine.

I cannot debug what the actual issue is here.

I want there to be encryption between the load balancer and the backend. So any other methods will be welcomed.

Comment: Firstly, the encryption is done by default by google at rest and in transit, no worries. Anyway, did you try to curl the VM private IP from another VM in the same VPC? your curl in localhost don't say if the service is available on the external port. In addition, did you check the firewall rules? You need to allow the health check to access to your machine.

Comment: Yes, curl works fine from another instance. It's just the issue from the health checks.

Comment: Show the command that you used testing from another instance. Your question shows **localhost** which cannot be accessed from a different instance. Show the listening ports on the instance.

Comment: curl -k https://<internal-ip>. I just used this.  
`apache2    5113            root    6u  IPv6  90781495      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)`

Answer (score 0):

1. The health check error is **TIMEOUT**. This means your backend did accept a connection on port 443.
2. Your question does not detail how Apache/Nginx? is configured.
3. Check that you have configured a port 443 listener in your web server.
4. Check if you have enabled a VPC firewall rule for port 443.
5. The default VPC firewall rule **default-all-https** allows traffic on port 443. You can optionally apply the **Network tag** named **https-server** to the VM instance.

Provided that the backend web service is running and listening on port 443, the following command will enable the default firewall rule for HTTPS port 443.

Apply the **https-server** network tag to a Compute Engine VM instance:

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [INSTANCE_NAME] \
--zone [INSTANCE_ZONE] \
--tags="https-server"
```

List your Compute Engine VM instances and review the tags:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="table(name,status,tags.list())"
```

Note: The above steps are good for debugging. However, that will allow the entire Internet to connect to your backend. A better solution is to create a firewal rule only allowing traffic from the load balancer and the health check service. The addresses to allow are:

- 130.211.0.0/22
- 35.191.0.0/16

The following command will create a VPC firewall rule allowing all instances to receive traffic from Google Cloud Load Balancers and Health Check services. This rule can be fine-tuned to assign to specific instances:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "lb-rule" --allow=tcp:80,tcp:443 \
--source-ranges="10.0.0.0/22,10.0.0.0/14" \
--source-ranges="130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16" \
--description="Allow traffic from load balancer and health check services"
```

Comment: 1. Yes the backend is not getting the request. That's what I am trying to figure out, why it is not working as all configuration seems to be correct.  
2. Apache is configured. curl HTTPS works fine.
3. Port 443 is listening on the instance  
4. Yes the HTTPS port is open  
5. I am using network tags with the CIDR for the LoadBalancers and health check services